# BindingList ListChanged event

Tags: bindinglist, listchanged

I am subscribing to the ListChanged event in a binding list. When the list changed (item is  add/removed), I will update an internal list. The internal list contains objects that are 1-1 corresponding to the items in the original list. The item order can be different.

Based on the document, when the event is fired, the ListChangedEventArgs.ListChangedType can be one of the followings: ItemAdded, ItemDeleted, Reset and ItemChanged. ListChangedType is ItemChanged when an item in the list is changed, either the item is replaced by another one or one of its property is modified.

How can I differentiate these cases so that I can reload the internal list if an item in the list is replaced by a different one, but do nothing if it's the property change?

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an item is being replaced the `ListChangedEventArgs` has an `OldIndex` of -1, it it is being updated both `OldIndex` and `NewIndex` have the same value.